# What is is difference between "As long as I am selling" and "As long as I can sell"?

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

I am reading a book. It says there is a bakery owner who wants everyone will be hungry for one thing - his donuts! So he invented a special donut recipe. As result, his donuts are turning people into zombies after they had his donuts.

> As long as **I am selling** lots of donuts, who cares?

> As long as **I can sell** lots of donuts, who cares?

I wonder why the author write the sentence in present progressive instead of present simple. What's difference between the two sentences?

Comment: "can sell" implies the ability or permission to sell, "am selling" doesn't. I can go swimming whenever I want, but I am not always swimming.

Answer (score 0):

The baker is happy with the present situation because:

> 1. He is currently selling a lot of doughnuts.
> 2. He is able to sell a lot of doughnuts.

Both are valid ways of expressing the same idea.